# Can some one explain me what does np.log do?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I understand that this is a simple question, but I couldnt get what exactly does np.log do? I saw the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.log.html) from which I am not able to understand the logic behind `np.log`. `np.log([9000000])` I am getting the output as 16.01273514. I couldnt understand why I am getting this number, I fo know what a [logarithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37993/what-is-log-what-does-it-mean-how-does-it-transform-a-number) means.

Comment: What is there to not understand? `np.log()` returns the natural logarithm.

Comment: Keep in mind this is the natural logarithm (inverse exponential function) and thus `ln(9000000) = 16.01273514` is correct.

Comment: @mattm What is the need for taking log of a column in a data frame?? Is there any specific rules for taking natural log??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`np.log(x)` is the natural logarithm, i.e.  the power to which `e` would have to be raised to equal `x`:

```
>>> np.log([1, np.e, np.e**2, 0])
array([  0.,   1.,   2., -Inf])
```

Base 10 logarithm:

```
>>> np.log10([1e-15, -3.])
array([-15.,  NaN])
```

Base 2 logarithm:

```
>>> x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 2**4])
>>> np.log2(x)
array([-Inf,   0.,   1.,   4.])
```

In your example:

```
>>> np.log([9000000])        # ln(9000000)
array([ 16.01273514])

>>> np.exp([16.01273514])    # e^16
array([ 9000000.04229556])
```

Comment: so basically log([9000000)] is equal to  2.718281828 ** 16 am I right??

Comment: Because `log([9000000)]=16` then `2.718281828 ** 16 = 9000000`.